# Binomial and probability

Tags: statistics

History indicates that 80% of all McDonald's customers order French fries with their meal purchases. During one afternoon at a slow restaurant, 15 people order meals. Assuming that all criteria for a binomial apply, what is the probability for each of the following>

a) Exactly 13 of the customers order fries?
I have 0.230

b) 14 or more customers order fries?
I have 0.035

Is what I have right?

Answer (score 0):

We have that the number of people ordering fries is $F \sim \mathrm{B}(15,0.8)$. We therefore have:

$$P(F=13) = \binom{15}{13}(0.8)^{13}(0.2)^{2}=0.2309$$

And:

$$P(F\geq 14) = \binom{15}{14}(0.8)^{14}(0.2) + \binom{15}{15}(0.8)^{15} = 0.167$$

Comment: so i had the first part right